# Super key not toggling activities

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on my new laptop but the Super key is not toggling activities. I tried to change the keybindings from settings> keyboard> System > Show the overview where it is set to Super + S, but it didn't work at all. I am used to using the `Super` key to toggle activities for 2 years and can't accept using any other key combination.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10):

I found the solution here https://github.com/ckb-next/ckb-next/issues/165

What it says is that there's a 'lock-key' with a locked windows logo at the top of your keyboard (for my case, it's F9) which disables the super key. You need to switch it on.

Comment: I have a Logitech G710+, and the 'lock-key' that produced the same effect is above F5 and looks like a block with a flag sticking out. In my case, I had to switch it off to get the super key working.

Comment: I have a Slimbook Pro and its the F2 key, it also has a lock icon, thanks man!

Comment: HP Omen laptop, FN + F12 key solved the problem.

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>, I think this combination toggles the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Comment: Yes this was the case for me as well

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for, I had this problem too. I solved it using the answer on this thread. https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-963759.html

Answer (score 2):

I have a G513 Carbon and my son hit some keys.
I was able to re-enable Super key using  <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here:: [Super key not working in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231863/super-key-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04)

In my case, the keyboard had an option to disable the super key at <kbd>F12</kbd> . Pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> solved the problem.